# Concatenate range names in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have 14 ranges defined in the macro below.  What I would like to do is copy and paste all of them in one for loop as opposed to individually. I was going to structure my for loop like this but I am not sure of the syntax of how to concatenate the object names and the variable i.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub GenerateNewReport()

Dim rng1 As Range


Set rng1 = FindHeader("Category", "Detail")
Set rng2 = FindHeader("RXCUI", "Detail")
Set rng3 = FindHeader("NDC", "Detail")
Set rng4 = FindHeader("DDI", "Detail")
Set rng5 = FindHeader("GPI", "Detail")
Set rng6 = FindHeader("Med Name", "Detail")
Set rng7 = FindHeader("Strength", "Detail")
Set rng8 = FindHeader("Dose Form", "Detail")
Set rng9 = FindHeader("FORMULARY_TIER", "Detail")
Set rng10 = FindHeader("QUANTITY_MAX", "Detail")
Set rng11 = FindHeader("QUANTITY_TIME", "Detail")
Set rng12 = FindHeader("PA_REQUIRED", "Detail")
Set rng13 = FindHeader("PA_Group_NAME", "Detail")
Set rng14 = FindHeader("STEP_THERAPY", "Detail")

rng1.AutoFilter _
field:=1, _
Criteria1:=Array("Immunological Agents", "antidepressants", "antipsychotics", "anticonvulsants", "antiretrovirals", "antineoplastics"), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues


For i = 2 To 14
'I know this is string concatenation but I am unsure how to do this for variable names...

rng & i.copy 
rng & i.paste


Next i




End Sub
```

Comment: you would like to obtain a new variable called `rng234567891011121314` ? i couldn't understand your problem

Comment: No, I would like to copy rng2 and paste it somewhere then do the same with rng3 and then rng4 etc.

Comment: @user4682535 where are they getting pasted - you've not specified a place to paste them to.

Comment: you need to add a line `Dim rng1 As Range` for each of the object variables you are going to use

Comment: Yes I know that. but how would I concatenate the names in the for loop? In other words how do I append the value of `i` onto the end of `rng`?

Comment: @user4682535 you don't - it is an object variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're not using the variables name anywhere else, you could create a collection of ranges and then use a for each loop, something like this:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rngcollec As New Collection
Dim rngitem as Range


Set rng1 = FindHeader("Category", "Detail")
Set rng2 = FindHeader("RXCUI", "Detail")
rngcollec.Add rng2
Set rng3 = FindHeader("NDC", "Detail")
rngcollec.Add rng3
Set rng4 = FindHeader("DDI", "Detail")
rngcollec.Add rng4
Set rng5 = FindHeader("GPI", "Detail")
rngcollec.Add rng5
Set rng6 = FindHeader("Med Name", "Detail")
rngcollec.Add rng6
Set rng7 = FindHeader("Strength", "Detail")
rngcollec.Add rng7
Set rng8 = FindHeader("Dose Form", "Detail")
rngcollec.Add rng8
Set rng9 = FindHeader("FORMULARY_TIER", "Detail")
rngcollec.Add rng9
Set rng10 = FindHeader("QUANTITY_MAX", "Detail")
rngcollec.Add rng10
Set rng11 = FindHeader("QUANTITY_TIME", "Detail")
rngcollec.Add rng11
Set rng12 = FindHeader("PA_REQUIRED", "Detail")
rngcollec.Add rng12
Set rng13 = FindHeader("PA_Group_NAME", "Detail")
rngcollec.Add rng13
Set rng14 = FindHeader("STEP_THERAPY", "Detail")
rngcollec.Add rng14

rng1.AutoFilter _
field:=1, _
Criteria1:=Array("Immunological Agents", "antidepressants", "antipsychotics", "anticonvulsants", "antiretrovirals", "antineoplastics"), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues


For Each rngitem in rngcollec

rngitem.copy 
rngitem.paste

Next
```